# Applescript: Application ID only working with default version

Tags: applescript, adobe, photoshop

I'm working on a script for Photoshop and was using application id "com.adobe.photoshop" to identify when Photoshop is open. Unfortunately this ONLY seems to work for whatever the default version is. I have several machines this needs to go on and they might have 3 or they might have 5 versions.

I'd like it to work with whatever version is currently open.

The only way I can think to do that is to have an initial check of

if application "Photoshop CS6" is running
set Appname to "Photoshop CS6
ect... ect... ect...

for each version, but that's messy and if the version doesn't exist it generates a popup asking for where that is located.

Any ideas? =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are sure that Photoshop is already launched at the time you are running your script, you can do the check by looking to all running processes as bellow :

```
tell application "System Events" to set PShop to name of every process where name contains "Photoshop"
set AppliName to item 1 of PShop
```

if Photoshop is not running at that time, I suggest you to have a script which looks to every files of folder Application whose name contains Photoshop.